# Java Average of MultiDimensional List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, average

I am having problem with calculating average for my multidimensional list. I read most of the questions and answers here and other places as well but I could not find a solution.

My codes generate a list with values as shown below (4 columns). I was trying to calculate the average for each column but I don't know how to. Since the list does not have the length property, I tried to convert the whole thing to an array so I can determine the length, then sum up and take average. The data was place in a hashmap (map) and then dump into a list (mapList). Would please show me how to do this? Really appreciate any inputs. Thank you!

```
Array  LinkedList ArrayList  Vector
[44, 40, 80, 81] 
[43, 56, 61, 42] 
[47, 34, 64, 41] 
[37, 39, 86, 66] 
[31, 30, 55, 43]
```

Here are the codes.

```
private void setMap(){
    // print headers
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%10s%8s\n","Array", "LinkedList",
            "ArrayList", "Vector");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberTimes; i++){

        // put calculated time into hashmap
        map.put("Array", timer.arrayTimes());
        map.put("LinkedList", timer.linkedTimes());
        map.put("ArrayList", timer.listTimes());
        map.put("Vector", timer.vectorTimes());                          

        // put hashmap values into List
        mapList = new ArrayList(map.values());                        

        // iterate through mapList list
        Iterator iter = mapList.iterator();                      

        // print hashmap values
        while (iter.hasNext()){         

             // print values in numbers
             System.out.printf("%-10d", iter.next());                 
         } // end while                          
        System.out.println();                          
    } // end for                                    
} // end setMap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an enhanced for-loop to loop through each element in the hash map, like the following:

```
private void setMap(){
    // print headers
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%10s%8s\n","Array", "LinkedList",
            "ArrayList", "Vector");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberTimes; i++){

        // put calculated time into hashmap
        map.put("Array", timer.arrayTimes());
        map.put("LinkedList", timer.linkedTimes());
        map.put("ArrayList", timer.listTimes());
        map.put("Vector", timer.vectorTimes());                          

        // Loops through each element of map.values() and assigns its value to the val variable
        for(String val : map.values()){
            System.out.printf("%-10d", val);
        }                          
        System.out.println();                          
    } // end for                                    
}
```

Please not that you will need to change "String" in the for loop to the data type held by the HashMap.
You can actually get the size of a hashMap by using the .size() method, for example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since the list does not have the length property, I tried to convert
>   the whole thing to an array so I can determine the length, then sum up
>   and take average.

List doesn't has the length property but size property. For example,

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
list.add((T) object1);
list.add((T) object2);
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Hope, this will set you to the path of getting the size of list.

So, if you put your list in map, iterate over the map, against each item of map, iterate through the size, count it and get the average.

Answer (score 1):

You made your code very messy and Complexity arises , so below is my code for finding average using Hashmap Technique.Refer below is my code , Understand this and again try to implement ..Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueQue {

public static float getAverage(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm, String name) {
    ArrayList<Integer> scores;
    scores = hm.get(name);
    if (scores == null) {
        System.out.println("NOT found");
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : scores) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return (float) sum / scores.size();
}
//Find the Best Student from these Key-Value Pair
public static String getBestStudent(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm) {
    double max = 0;
    String beststudent = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> x : hm.entrySet()) {
        String name = x.getKey();
        double average = getAverage(hm, name);
        if (average > max) {
            max = average;
            beststudent = name;
        }
    }
    return beststudent;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("Peter", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);

    hm.put("Nancy", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Nancy").add(7);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);

    hm.put("Lily", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(8);

    System.out.println("Find the average of the Peter");
    float num = getAverage(hm, "Peter");
    System.out.println(num);
    String name = getBestStudent(hm);
    System.out.println(name);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArrayList > stringarray_name = new ArrayList >() 
You can use the ouuter array list.size () to find the total row and then process each row adding the values and find the average.